# How Calculate Expire Date in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have this query for expiry date calculation and its work fine but result show in - eg:-9 year 4 month and 5 day.

I want to show that in normal way like "Expire in 9 years 4 months and 5 day":

```
DECLARE @TempDate Datetime ,
        @ExpiryDate Datetime, 
        @year     int,
        @month    int,
        @day      int

SET @ExpiryDate = (SELECT TOP (1) [ExpiryDate] FROM [dbo].[Purchases] WHERE [ProductId] = 1)

SELECT @TempDate = @ExpiryDate

SELECT 
    @year = DATEDIFF(YEAR, @TempDate, GETDATE()) -
            CASE
                WHEN (MONTH(@ExpiryDate) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR
                (MONTH(@ExpiryDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@ExpiryDate) > DAY(GETDATE()))
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END
SELECT @TempDate = DATEADD(YEAR, @year, @TempDate)

SELECT @month = DATEDIFF(MONTH, @TempDate, GETDATE()) - 
            CASE
                WHEN DAY(@ExpiryDate) > DAY(GETDATE())
                THEN 1 ELSE 0
            END
SELECT @TempDate = DATEADD(MONTH, @month, @TempDate)

SELECT @day = DATEDIFF(DAY, @TempDate, GETDATE())

SELECT @year AS Years, @month AS Months, @day AS [Days]
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic would all really help.

Comment: do you want the output in the format "Expire in 9 years 4 months and 5 day"  ?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing in your query, but it could likely be resolved with just one single sql query

Comment: you can always concatenate varchar message with the variables, right? if I understood the question correctly then SELECT 'Expire in ' + convert(varchar(10), @year) + ' years '+ convert(varchar(10), @month) + ' months and ' + convert(varchar(10), @day) + ' days.' should work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the calculation is working as you expect but you want the `Years` value to be returned as a positive rather than negative number. If this is the case, you should change the final `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT (@year * -1) AS Years, @month AS Months, @day AS [Days];
```

Alternatively if you want to return the output as a string (i.e. Expire in 9 years 4 months and 5 day), change the final `SELECT` to:

```
SELECT 'Expire in ' + CAST((@year * -1) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' years ' 
    + CAST(@month AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' months and ' 
    + CAST(@day AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' day';
```

Casting as `VARCHAR(2)` assumes that you expect no more than 99 years, but you may want to increase that number.